# How to do addition of two columns data and display it in the third column

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am inserting values 1,2 and 3 in the 3 column of a gridview and in the fourth column, i am expecting to get the answer as 6 but in the fourth column the values are getting append and the value is like 123 in the fourth column. Below i have pasted the code

```
protected void OnRowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    string ID = (row.Cells[1].Text);
   string Assignment_Marks =(row.Cells[2].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
   string Viva_Marks = (row.Cells[3].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
   string Midterm_Marks = (row.Cells[4].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
   string Overall_Marks = (row.Cells[5].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
    string status = (row.Cells[6].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StudentConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE users SET Assignment_Marks = @Assignment_Marks, Viva_Marks = @Viva_Marks, Midterm_Marks = @Midterm_Marks, Overall_Marks= @Overall_Marks, status=@status where div='A' and year='3' and stream='IT' and ID=@ID"))
        {
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Assignment_Marks", Assignment_Marks);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Viva_Marks", Viva_Marks);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Midterm_Marks", Midterm_Marks);
  Overall_Marks = Assignment_Marks + Viva_Marks + Midterm_Marks;//It is use to append i know, then what to use 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Overall_Marks", Overall_Marks);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    this.BindGrid();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because all variables are string type, when you plus two string, it will append.
You have to convert string to int type, then it will sum up all numbers.

```
int SumUp = Int32.Parse(Assignment_Marks) + Int32.Parse(Viva_Marks) + Int32.Parse(Midterm_Marks);
Overall_Marks = SumUp.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Above mentioned values are stored in string format.So we want to convert the decimal format.Because marks may be in decimal format.eg:70.5

Please tell me below mentioned code is working or not.If this answer is useful to you click the answer option and like.

```
decimal OM=0m;    OM=Convert.ToDecimal(Assignment_Marks)+Convert.ToDecimal(Viva_Marks)+Convert.ToDecimal(Midterm_Marks);
Overall_Marks = OM.ToString();
```